# Save currently running script in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scripting, save

Is there a way of saving the currently running script in Matlab?  I have a script which automatically takes a backup of a set of scripts although if I have changed the current script then the saved  version will be out of date.

Perhaps its possible to call some java?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the backup-script should backup itself as well?

Comment: yes, in part,  I have a main script which sets lots of parameters which then calls a function which backs up the whole set of scripts.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand you 100%. Do you backup by saving the paramters as a mat file, or the scripts themselves as m files? Do you just save a copy in a separate folder/tag? Why is the saved version out-of-date? An example would help.

Comment: I save the m files individually and then save the parameters separately in a mat file. Its a bit convoluted I know.  I save the whole set of scripts so that I can run them again at a later date without too many changes.  Occasionally I forget to click save on the script which sets the current parameters and so the file which gets copied on disk does not contain the correct contents.  If I could save it from the script, the saved copy would always be right.

Comment: Ok now it's clearer. It means you do not always run the script by typing its name in the command line, but rather by the 'Evaluate cell' button, right? Otherwise you are running the saved file, not the edited file.

Comment: Yes that's right. From time to time I'll run the script from the start, but it involves loading a lot of data so I tend to try to avoid reloading it, but I still want a record of the complete script set.  Its a bit of a kludge for a version control system (I also have some of the code in SVN)

Comment: In that case, I don't know of any way to do it. You can break the code to sub-scripts and run only a sub-script from the command line, to avoid running/loading the parts you want to skip.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I'll have a look at [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere on Yair Altman's site (see link in my other answer) he also referred to [a blog entry about editorservices](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/10/26/the-matlab-editor-at-your-fingertips/), which was introduced with MATLAB R2009b.

```
editorservices.getActive().save
```

should do what you want.

Comment: That's great,  I can even tell if the files have been modified by looking at the IsDirty field.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, all I write here I learned from [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor/) by [Yair Altman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman), in particular by looking into his [EditorMacro.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24615)... great stuff!

I'm assuming that Itamar Katz understood you correctly and that you are running unsaved code from the editor by using "Evaluate Cell" or "Evaluate Selection"; you want your code to realize that it is not saved and save the version currently displayed in the editor to some other location.

I have not found a way to *save* the file directly to the original location, but at least I have found a way to *access* the current text. You can then use fprintf to save it to wherever you want. I have tested this in Matlab 7.11 (R2010b); if you have a different version you'd need to dig through EditorMacro.m to find the correct code for Matlab 6.

```
if  com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.isDirty    
    thisdocument=com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.getDocument;
    thisdocument_text=char(thisdocument.getText(0,thisdocument.getLength));
    fid = fopen('backupfile.m','w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s', thisdocument_text);
    fclose(fid);
else
    % saved file is unmodified in editor - no need to play tricks...
    ...
end
```

So the if-condition checks if the currently active editor window contains a file which is not saved ("dirty"); if it is, we need to retrieve the current version of the code (into variable thisdocument_text) and save this string to some file.

Does this help?

Comment: I decided to leave this answer in even though I have a better one now, given they are unrelated and this one hints at much deeper ways to mess with MATLAB internals. This is the "undocumented" answer, while the other one uses stuff which was referred to as only "semi-undocumented"...