# Programmatically save all dirty files in MatLab

Tags: matlab, macros, editor

Frequently I make the mistake of running my `main.m` when several files in the editor are dirty.

It would be nice if I could have a command at the start of my `main.m` that just automatically saves every dirty file.

[Save currently running script in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389528/save-currently-running-script-in-matlab) gives an answer with a clue for saving the ***currently active*** file, but is there a way to do this for **ALL** files?

Comment: I suggest you clarify the meaning of "dirty" here (files that have been modified but not saved) for the benefit of non-native speakers

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorservice`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor) object to access the editor and save all dirty files.

```
service = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices;

% Get a vector of all open editors
editors = service.getEditorApplication.getOpenEditors();

% For each editor, if it is dirty, save it
for k = 0:(editors.size - 1)
    editor = editors.get(k);

    if editor.isDirty()
        editor.save();
    end
end
```

Rather than blindly saving *all* files, you could modify this slightly so that you could pass a list of functions (your dependencies) and just save those.

```
function saveAll(varargin)
    % Convert all filenames to their full file paths
    filenames = cellfun(@which, varargin, 'uniformoutput', false);

    service = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices;

    % Get a vector of all open editors
    editors = service.getEditorApplication.getOpenEditors();

    % For each editor, if it is dirty, save it
    for k = 0:(editors.size - 1)
        editor = editors.get(k);

        % Check if the file in this editor is in our list of filenames
        % and that it's dirty prior to saving it
        if ismember(char(editor.getLongName()), filenames) && editor.isDirty()
            editor.save();
        end
    end
end
```

And this could be called with multiple function names (as strings)

```
saveAll('myfunc', 'myotherfunc')
```

Comment: Thanks!  (btw it appears `editors.get(k-1);` is necessary due to 0-based i.e. sane indexing).  Unfortunately this solution doesn't quite work. If I dirty my `main.m` file (containing that script) then run it I get ***"java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot save to main.m while it is being debugged. Exit debug mode and try again."***

Comment: @Pi Thanks for pointing out that indexing issue. It says that you are in debug mode, is that the case? Have you tried running it when you're not in debug mode?